# Django IntegrityError with DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

I have field in my model as follows.

```
    view_time = ArrayField(
    models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True))
```

but i get error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "view_time"violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (18, 0, null, null, null).
```

error arises when i try to create new object, and add value:

```
    recent_views = UserRecentViews.objects.create()
    recent_views.add_view(product.article)
```

i use django 1.8.8 and Python 3.5.2

i reset database fiew times but it doesn`t help, db is Postgres.

I think problem in object creation? but why django can not create object with current datetime? auto_now_add=True was added for this.

My question is how add autogenerated datetime field with django?

Comment: Have you tried adding the [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) argument to your `ArrayField` ?

Comment: Yes, i try, no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your database appears to be incompletely normalized. The use of comma separate values in a column or an array type is usually a good indication of that.

Secondly.

> Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be
>   a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a
>   row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier
>   to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of
>   elements.

[Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/arrays.html) are just postgresql's way of giving you enough rope to ...

Your best bet really is to normalize your database. Your inferior option is to set blank=True, null = True

```
view_time = ArrayField(
    models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True), blank=True, null=True)
```

That's because when you do the following django has no reason to create any DateTimeField objects at all.

```
recent_views = UserRecentViews.objects.create()
```

So it just sets the array field as null, which is not allowed.

Oh to be more specific

> but why django can not create object with current datetime

because you are not telling it to.

Comment: Now i do this: 

`view_time = ArrayField(
        models.DateTimeField(_('recent views'), default=timezone.now), blank=True, null=True)`

now, no more errors, but view_time field empty.

Comment: ok, please tell me how fill this fields with auto-generated current datetime?

Comment: Your question was how to solve an intergrity error and I have answered that correctly. Please post a new question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions

Comment: I was getting a similar error when creating an array of strings,

`tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100), blank=True)`,

but doing this instead fixed the issue:

`tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(default="", max_length=100), blank=True, default=list)`

Comment: Don't use arrayfields for anything. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134260/django-jsonfield-inside-arrayfield/41134445#41134445