# Django JSONField inside ArrayField

Tags: python, arrays, json, django, postgresql

I have a problem inserting to a field using ArrayField with JSONField inside.

**models.py**

```
locations = ArrayField(JSONField(null = True,blank = True), blank=True, null = True)
```

**Insert**

```
location_arr = [{"locations" : "loc1","amount":Decimal(100.00)},{"locations" : "loc2","amount":Decimal(200.25)}]
instance.locations = location_arr
instance.save()
```

When I do this, I got

> column "locations" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[]
>
> LINE 1: ...d" = 2517, "locations" = ARRAY['{"loc...
>
> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

So I tried to dump it using:

```
import json
location_arr = [{"locations" : "loc1","amount":Decimal(100.00)},{"locations" : "loc2","amount":Decimal(200.25)}]
instance.locations = json.dumps(location_arr)
instance.save()
```

then I got this

> LINE 1: ...d" = 2517, "locations" = '[{"loc":...
>
> DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.

I am using:

1. Django 1.9
2. Python 2.7
3. Postgres 9.4.10
4. psycopg2 2.6.2

Comment: This is [known bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28291).

Comment: This was fixed in `Django==2.2a1`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Arrays

First of all, let's take a close look at this important text from the [Postgresql Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/arrays.html) document.

> Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be
>   a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a
>   row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier
>   to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of
>   elements.

Most of the time, you should not be using arrays.

### JSONB

JSONB is available in Django as the JSONField type. This field is more scalable and flexible than array fields and can be searched more efficiently. However if you find yourself searching inside JSONB fields all the time the above statement about Arrays is equally valid for JSONB.

Now what do you have in your system? A an array that holds JSONB field. This is a disaster waiting to happen. Please normalize your data.

### Recap

> so when to use ArrayField?

On the rare occasion when you don't need to search in that column and you don't need to use that column for a join.

Comment: Thanks. so when to use ArrayField?

Comment: On the rare occaision when you don't need to search in that column and you don't need to use that column for a join.

Comment: How about we use custom lookups like __contains for searching? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains

Comment: and that doesn't search the arrayfield?

Comment: no worries glad to have been of service. All the best with your project

Comment: This answer is quite out-of-date - now that Postgres supports GIN indexes on JSONB columns (with the crazy fast `?` operator for array/key membership), storing tags in a column instead of a join table can help you avoid massive join fan-out during queries and is a totally reasonable solution.

Comment: On the contrary Ben, you are following a well known SQL anti pattern by putting comma seperated data in a column.

Answer (score 7):

I have encountered the same scenario. Here is the way how I solved it

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import JSONField as JSONBField
location = JSONBField(default=list,null=True,blank=True)
```

**insert**

```
model_object.location = [{"locations" : "loc1","amount":Decimal(100.00)},{"locations" : "loc2","amount":Decimal(200.25)}]
```

**update**

```
model_object.location.append({"locations" : "loc1","amount":Decimal(100.00)})
model_object.save()
```

This worked for me in
 Django - 2.0.2
 Postgres - 9.5
 psycopg2 - 2.7.4
 python - 3.4.3

Comment: now how do you search for a particular location inside JSONBField, let's say with locations="loc1"?

Answer (score 4):

You can sidestep this issue by using the JSONField as the column field type with a `list` as the root element.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
class MyDBArray(models.Model):
    array_data = models.JSONField(default=list)

my_db_array = MyDBArray(array_data=[1, 2, 3])
my_db_array.save()
```

You would need to validate in the `save` method that the `array_data` field is actually list-like.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in the latest [unreleased version of Django 2.2a1](https://github.com/django/django/releases/tag/2.2a1)

`pip install Django==2.2a1`

PS I believe that it will work with versions `>= 2.2a1`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is to turn the field from an array of jsonfield into a jsonfield. Just add a key to the location_arr.

Related thread: [ArrayField with JSONField as base_field in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037589/arrayfield-with-jsonfield-as-base-field-in-django)