# Postgresql - distinct values from jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following jsonb array column (tags)

```
|name | tags (jsonb)   |
--------------------------------
|john | [ "foo", "bar" ]
|smith| [ "bar", "bat" ]
|adam | [ "foo", "dot" ]
```

How to get the distinct tags as follows
["foo", "bar", "bat", "dot"] ?

Comment: I think you meant `["foo", "bar", "bat", "dot"]`, you wrote `bar` twice here.

Comment: @fpietka yes, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: did you try my answer

Comment: @e4c5, not yet.. tied up with few other things.. sure will check out and leave the feedback!

Comment: When you post questions here, you are asking people to take the time to read it And then some of those readers will take the time to think and write an answer. Surely the leat that you can do is to allocate some of your own time to try out those answers??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will solve your particular problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM
  (SELECT name, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(tags) as b FROM my_table) AS foo;
```

however you have a bigger problem. Storing tags like this is a mistake that's repeated far too often. You should normalize your table. Please see [Django JSONField inside ArrayField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134260/django-jsonfield-inside-arrayfield/41134445#41134445)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've normalized the model and looks much cleaner to work with and maintain.

Comment: glad to have been of help

Comment: FYI the normalization suggestion in this answer is a bit out-of-date - now that Postgres supports GIN indexes on JSONB columns (with the crazy fast `?` operator for testing for array/keys), storing tags in a JSONB column instead of a join table can help you avoid massive fan-out during queries and is a totally reasonable solution.

Comment: On the contrary Ben, you are following a well known SQL anti pattern by putting comma seperated data in a column.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution works, but can be simplified:

```
SELECT DISTINCT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(tags) AS tag FROM yourtable;
```

Also, while it's true that this might be an anti-pattern in many cases, there are still valid uses for this, as long as you are aware of its drawbacks (joining and searching will be more difficult).