# save postgres arrayfield using modelform

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with `ArrayField` and I want save data using `ModelForm`. But my problem is every time only the first value from array is saving . How do I save whole array from form ?  Here is my code:

model:

```
class Reminder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    provider_type = (
        ('Em', 'Email'),
        ('Sm', 'SMS'),
        ('De', 'Desktop'),
        ('Mo', 'Mobile'),
    )
    notification = ArrayField(models.CharField(choices=provider_type, max_length=2, default='Em'))
```

form:

```
class ReminderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reminder
        exclude = ('user', )
```

view:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reminder_form = ReminderForm(request.POST)
        if reminder_form.is_valid():
            form = reminder_form.save(commit=False)
            user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user.username)
            form.user = user
            form.save()
        else:
            .....
        return redirect('create')
    return render(request, 'add.html')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django JSONField inside ArrayField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134260/django-jsonfield-inside-arrayfield)

Comment: @e4c5 I think my problem is different .

Comment: your problem is very much the same - basically you shouldn't be using ArrayField here