# What jsonb type would be better (jsonb or jsonb[] array)?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a field in my database in which I store the details which is an array

```
[{
 "id": "16d94b2b-d0e6-49dd-90a9-8acd323b19fa", 
 "name": "Pollo parmessano", "price": "40.00", "quantity": "2", 
 "variation": null, 
 "product_id": "4af95410-3fd0-4316-8da0-830ce92b40f1"
}, {
 "id": "bb1f984f-f0b3-4a55-8a4b-35fa9afac5cc", 
 "name": "Camaron al Ajo", "price": "120.00", "quantity": "1", 
 "variation": "super", 
 "product_id": "69efc835-cfcd-4a3b-8c7e-bc5e8ba88196"
}]
```

So far it works nice with just `jsonb` but I would like to know if I use `jsonb[]` **array** would be a better fit, what would be a good reason or argument for selecting one over the other?

Comment: *better fit* would be f.ex. a proper normalization. your example data seems structured enough to use actual, typed columns. -- if you insist on using some JSON representation, in any means, please don't use `jsonb[]`. it has literally no benefit.

Comment: I agree with pozs. `jsonb[]` seems pretty much useless. Plus: if you store the array as a real JSON array inside a single JSON document you can operate on that using all Postgres json functions - something you couldn't do if you put each element into a separate JSON document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django JSONField inside ArrayField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134260/django-jsonfield-inside-arrayfield)