# Efficiently querying JSON with nested arrays in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to query a JSON data structure in Postgres (9.6 on Amazon RDS). The data contains an array of objects, which in turn has an element that contains an array of objects. I'd like to find all records that match a key + value in one of those nested arrays.

Given rows like this:

```
{"drinkers" : [
  {"name" : "geoff", 
   "beers" : [
     {"name": "PBR"},
     {"name" : "Bud Select"}
    ]}, 
  {"name" : "tom", 
   "beers" : [
     {"name": "Bud Light"},
     {"name" : "Busch"}
    ]}
]}
```

I want to find all rows where there's a drinkers.beers object that's name is "PBR". The closest I've come is this:

```
select jsonb_data 
from bars 
where jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'drinkers') -> 'beers') ->> 'name' = 'PBR'``
```

But this does not work since the where returns a list instead of a single true/false to match on. I've come up other solutions using sub queries, lateral joins, etc but all these solutions have performance issues, even with proper gin indexes. Any suggestions on how to query a data structure like this in Postgres?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django JSONField inside ArrayField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134260/django-jsonfield-inside-arrayfield)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try using the `IN` operator?

```
WHERE 'PBR' IN (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'drinkers') -> 'beers') ->> 'name'
);
```

Another approach would be to use JSONB `contain` (i.e. `@>`):

```
WHERE data -> 'drinkers' @> '[{"beers": [{"name": "PBR"}]}]';
```

Comment: ANd this is how index could looks like (it works for me):  create index on table_name using gin ((data -> 'drinkers') jsonb_path_ops);

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this should probably just be a comment, but if the statement which returns the names gives you a list or array, can you perhaps use `'PBR' = ANY jsonb_array_elements(...`?