# How to make a model in django without predefined attributes?

Tags: python, django

I am little bit confused with the django model as the title said. I also cannot find any posts in google.

Let's say in the normal way, we will have a model like this:

```py
class something(models.Model):
    fName = models.TextField()
    lName = models.TextField()
    ......
    lastThings = models.TextField()
```

However, I don't want to have a model like this. I want to have a model with no predefined attributes. In order words, I can put anythings into this model. My thought is like can I use a loop or some other things to create such model?

```py
class someModel(models.Model):
    for i in numberOfModelField:
        field[j] = i
        j+=1
```

This is table A to read:

```py
A  B  C
1  2  3
2  3  4
```

This is table B to read:

```py
A B C D E F G G G
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
...............
4 5 3 2 4 5 6 4 3
```

And so different kind of table can be read

Therefore, I can have a model that fit in any cases. I am not sure is it clear enough to let you understand my confuse. Thank you

Comment: But a model represents a table in the database. How would it store data if you didn't define the db columns?

Comment: This isn't really the django way of doing things. You can have array fields, but I'm wondering what your use case is. I strongly suspect this isn't the way you want to go about solving it.

Comment: um... actually I want to read a dataframe or a excel file to the database, would you suggest a solution to handle the model???

Comment: Is it mean that all the excel or dataframe I read to my database should have the same fields? I am trying to do a excel reader which can read different excel and save it to database

Comment: Without knowing your exact cases, and to load a "generic" excel sheet, I'd key a table using row and column ID (and some kind of sheet ID), then load to that. That's a "standard" table definition, and just as flexible as field[0], field[1], field[2] ... field[n], if not more so.

Comment: Thanks urbanespaceman, but can you give me some more example or some sample code? I am still confused. And I have edited the question to see is it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment (put as an answer so I can format the code decently).

```
class something(models.Model):
    sheet_name = models.TextField()
    row = models.TextField()
    col = models.TextField()
    cell_value = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [[sheet_name, row, col]]
```

Once you have the values in this format you can do what you want with them. If you know the first row is always headers you could define a header table keyed on sheet_name and col, and map them to header_name as well, or you could just take them from this table.

There's probably better ways of handling this, and I'm still not sure of your use case. If this is loading data temporarily to use in other processes, then this should be fine. If it's to populate some new database for use indefinitely, then you need to spend more time defining the actual tables, though this process would be OK as an intermediate staging area just to get the data out of excel.

Comment: thank you so much, I will try it to see if it is work

Comment: um.... sorry can you explain a bit more?? If the model like this: first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) I could know it is used for storing one cell data, but what should be in the row col and cell_value???

Comment: first_name? What model are you using now? In my model, the sheet name is to distinguish the different sheets you're loading (could also specify table name or something else, but it should probably be unique), row and col are the Excel row and col, and the cell_value is the value of the Excel cell.

Comment: I have taken a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630642/its-possible-to-store-an-array-in-django-model 
Is it a good way to store dataframe while using json as a attribute of model??