# Python List into Django model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to add an ip list (ex. ['192.168.0.1','...',]) into Django Model TextField.
I don't know the serializer and validator well, so I keep getting the error 'not a valid string'.
How can I change it?

Comment: You say you keep getting the error `not a valid string`, please show your code that yielded this error to help in understanding

Comment: Your question may already be answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630642/its-possible-to-store-an-array-in-django-model

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Thank you for the link. I'm reading it now, and it would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are most probably trying to save list in text field, which will not be possible, you can use array fields

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

```
class ChessBoard(models.Model):
    board = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
            size=8,
        ),
        size=8,
    )
```