# How can i use loop to create list of fields

Tags: python, django, list, field, modelform

Recently, I start project using django 3 I face the problem with model

I want to create the modelform and the field is a list:

Like answer1, answer2, ..., answer10,...

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
   question = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.question
quiz = Quiz.objects.all()
class Answer(models.Model):
   answer1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   answer2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   answer3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   ...
   answer10 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   ...
```

How I use loop or something  to declare this answer field?

Can I set my table column name of

```
answer1 = quiz[0].question
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44630696/9067016

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what database you are using, but you could use `ArrayField` if you are using PostreSQL instead of creating many similar columns.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Comment: Is it possible to store fielfield in arrayfield ?

Comment: No, I believe you can only store primitive types inside the array field