# How to put array of names in CharField Django

Tags: django, django-models

**In Models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    following = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user')
```

I want to pass an array of names of following persons in profile model

Also I am using sqlite3 database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630642/is-it-possible-to-store-an-array-in-django-model

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `PostgreSQL` and `ArrayField`
2. Convert array to string

   string = ','.join([str(key) for key in array_verb])