# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type text[] to jsonb

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-jsonfield

I was trying to include JSONField in my model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
class Trigger(models.Model):
    solutions = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

However, when I try to migrate the database, it gives the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type text[] to jsonb
LINE 1: ...ALTER COLUMN "solutions" TYPE jsonb USING "solutions"::jsonb
```

What could be done here?

Comment: This was a bug in Django, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54519268/5751147

Answer (score 24):

You can update the migration file from

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='foo',
        name='bar',
        field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.JSONField(blank=True, default=dict),
    ),
]
```

to

```
operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='foo',
        name='bar',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='foo',
        name='bar',
        field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.JSONField(blank=True, default=dict),
    ),
]
```

Comment: Where is this code? I searched in settings.py but can't find "operations"

Comment: Sorry, I found the migrations folder

Answer (score 5):

Error shows that you are trying to `alter column and not add a new` one. This column `solutions` seems to be declared as a Textfield (or Charfield) previously with data in it, which you are trying to convert to JSON field. That's why you are getting this error.

Better create a new field rather than altering a text field to JSON field and remove the previous field, if that is unnecessary.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Trigger(models.Model):
    new_solutions = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: removing previous field and create a new one is working for me

Comment: If you want to retain the same name, all you have to do is comment the field, then do a `makemigrations` + `migrate` to completely remove the field, then uncomment  that same field and add the modifications you'll like to do, then do another `makemigrations` + `migrate`.