# ArrayField with JSONField as base_field in Django

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-models, models

I have a GooglePlace model with a field to store the address_components being returned by Google Places API.

model.py

```
address_components = ArrayField(JSONField(), null=True, blank=True)
```

I am trying to store the data like this

```
address_components = [component for component in google_place_details.get("address_components")]
```

But I am getting this error :

> column "address_components" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of
>   type text[] LINE 1: ...
>
> '2018-04-26T07:49:02.101395+00:00'::timestamptz, ARRAY['{"l...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

I tried json.dumps each component, encode. But I think I am missing something silly.

Any help will be much appreciated

This is sample response :

```
"address_components":[  
   {  
      "long_name":"Chennai",
      "short_name":"Chennai",
      "types":[  
         "locality",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "long_name":"Ramagiri Nagar",
      "short_name":"Ramagiri Nagar",
      "types":[  
         "sublocality_level_2",
         "sublocality",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "long_name":"Velachery",
      "short_name":"Velachery",
      "types":[  
         "sublocality_level_1",
         "sublocality",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "long_name":"Chennai",
      "short_name":"Chennai",
      "types":[  
         "administrative_area_level_2",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "long_name":"Tamil Nadu",
      "short_name":"TN",
      "types":[  
         "administrative_area_level_1",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "long_name":"India",
      "short_name":"IN",
      "types":[  
         "country",
         "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "long_name":"600042",
      "short_name":"600042",
      "types":[  
         "postal_code"
      ]
   }
],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the JSON data in an `ArrayField`. You can store your `address_components` list directly into a `JSONField`.

Comment: I tried this `GooglePlace.objects.get_or_create(**google_place_details)` still getting the same error

Comment: Did you change the `address_components`model field to a `JSONField`?

Comment: I got that. You need to change it to be only `JSONField`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks man that worked. But what if I want to store it as Array of JSON ?

Comment: It will be stored as JSON in DB now and retrieved as a `list` of `dict`s.

If you want to store AND retrieve JSON encoded strings use an `ArrayField` of `TextField`s and json encode each list item in python.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28291.

I have refactored my model to JSONField()

From : `address_components = ArrayField(JSONField(), null=True, blank=True)`

To : `address_components = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)`