# Doubts how to design data with Django and PostgreSQL when having a value for every hour of the year

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

I am running a django app with PostgreSQL as my database. I have a building model called building. From this model I create many building instances. I have another model which is called forests from which I create many forests instances. (Let's assume I have even more models for which the same applies)

Now I want to add data (let's call it x) for every building and for every forest for every hour of the year. That means I will have 8760 values for every building and forest instance.

```
For instance: 
Hour1 : 234
Hour2 : 667
...
HourX : x
...
Hour8760: 34
```

These 8760 values will be added, roughly estimated, 10-15 times a day, so that could lead to 131400 values a day.

Now, I have doubts on how to design that. I thought I could go with a model like so:

```
class Hour(models.Model):
    building                = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    forest                  = models.ForeignKey(Forest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hour                    = models.IntegerField(...)
    value                   = models.FloatField(...)
    timestamp               = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

My second thought is to design it with a JSONField like discussed here: [Django JSONField inside ArrayField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134260/). 
So maybe I could save a dictionary for every building and every forest OR have a separate model that stores this dictionary like `{hour1:value, hour2:value}`

My question is what the best way would be to design what I have in mind? Is there a better way that I don't consider?

I am also thinking for option1: For every value I would create a new Object of Hour. That is a lot of instances and I am scared my database gets bloated or that PostgreSQL has trouble handling it.

I am looking for some guidance for this.

I would like to stick with PostgreSQL even though I read about InfluxDB and Timescale. I think PostgreSQL is very powerful and should be able to handle this. I guess attached to my question is also if it is still reasonable with the amount of data I have to handle to stick with PostgrSQL, which I hope. Last but not least I also want to write an API for it which is probably not relevant but I add it anyway.

Any guidance, hints and help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to understand, when you say "131400 values a day", is that because you're adding 10-15 new buildings/forests each day? Or will one building have 10-15 * 8760 hours added each day, meaning we have to multiply this by the number of buildings?

Comment: The other question is, what are you going to do with this `Hour` data? Do you need to be able to do complex aggregate queries on this? Or is it sufficient to retrieve the full list of values for one building every now and then?

Comment: Thanks for the reply dirkgroten. To clarify: One building have 10-15 * 8760 hours added each day. It is updating the data but also keeping it for comparison. Well, the queries won't be extremely complicated.  But they will have a certain complexity. It is not enough to just show a full list. Use case could be: For hour x in a specific building I need value y. Or maybe, for a certain range of hours give me xyz-thousand values.... Do I express myself comprehensibly?